# Apple Push Notification issue

Tags: notifications, push

I am trying to implement APNS for my App and am hitting a wall while trying to generate a provisioning profile. I followed the instructions to create an APP id and was able to generate an SSL certificate for my App (the type is shown to be APNs development IOS). However, when I try to generate a provisioning profile, following the screen where I choose the AppID of my app, I do not see the SSL certificate I generate for this app. In the certificates list, I only see a certificate of type 'IOS development' that was created previously. I have been stuck on this issue for a while. Can someone please help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my own query. we need to add iOS development certificate while creating profile for APNS. You should have the p12 of that iOS development certificate.